# 3rd loop doesn't perform export but the first 2 did

Tags: vba, ms-access

i have a large procedure, it's supposed to loop through all files in the folder and perform a bunch of stuff. all works fine if there are 2 files in the folder. if there are 3 (i haven't tried 4 or 5), on the 3rd loop one line (all the rest works fine) doesn't do anything.

there's nothing wrong with the code, otherwise, it wouldn't have worked for the first 2 files

on the 3rd run, it goes into the IF, gets to that line, goes through it (i debugged through it, so i myself pressed F8, so i know that it passed there) but the excel file in the folder is the one from before. the MS Access table that this is exported from is correct

I'm so lost

this is the line
**DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, CurProjectNameUpper & "_TOMATCH", MatchLoadPath & "TOMATCH.xlsx", True**

```
If CreateMatchFileFromLoad = -1 Then 

If fExistTable(CurProjectNameUpper & "_TOMATCH") Then
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, CurProjectNameUpper & "_TOMATCH"
End If
                                  
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "ODBC", NewConnect, acTable, CurProjectNameUpper & "_" & VOracleName, CurProjectNameUpper & "_TOMATCH", False, True
                                  
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, CurProjectNameUpper & "_TOMATCH", MatchLoadPath & "TOMATCH.xlsx", True
End If
```

Comment: It appears `If fExistTable(CurProjectNameUpper & "_TOMATCH")` is evaluating to `False` on the 3rd iteration. Did you establish this when debugging?

Comment: Another thought - do you have any error handling or error handling turned off above this snippet of code (i.e. `On Error Resume Next`)?

Comment: I have it turned off but it passes through that line! I debugged line by line to trace where the problem is and what it might be skipping. And it goes inside the IF, goes through all lines and I myself pressed F8 on the line in question. It ran and went to End If. But the file didn't update. This is so weird.

Comment: I dont like error handling. I use these apps and I want it to go in debugging on error, so that I can see which line is giving me issues. Errors don't help me, they're too general.

Comment: Sorry, just realized you're talking about a different IF. That one doesn't matter at all, even if it skipped (but it doesn't). All it does is delete a table and if it evaluates to false, then it goes to the next 2 lines. Worst case scenario, the table isn't deleted and I get an error on import, because there's a table there with that name

Comment: When you debug, what are the values of the variables passed to DoCmd.TransferDatabase and DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet in both the second and third iterations?

Comment: the values are the same on all iterations. the reason these are variables is because this db is used for 60 different automations but within a project, the values will always be the same: same project name, same folder to export to and same VOracle name, which is _LOAD. So, the loop for this project is supposed take each file in the folder and perform an identical set of actions with it.